# What debug information is available on iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, logs

Is there any logs that would give (for example) some indication of what caused `Unable to connect to X` errors when trying to connect to a Wifi hotspot, with iOS 7.x?

The seeming lack of information as to the cause of many failures + error messages on this OS doesn't help technical people like myself start the troubleshooting processes anywhere logical.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two possibilites to get log information.

First sync your device with your Laptop / PC via iTunes. Then go to:

OS X

```
~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/<your iPhone’s name>/
```

Windows XP

```
%APPDATA%\Apple\Logs\CrashReporter\<your iPhone’s name>\
```

Windows Vista+

```
%APPDATA%\Apple\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\<your iPhone’s name>\
```

Second use the [iPhone Configuration Tool](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465) from Apple.

Comment: Thanks CML. Had I known that this would involve another device, would have stated that I run Linux, and try to stay away from iTunes at all costs. Also, for others reading you helpful answer: 1) There appears to be no profile name place holders in the Windows profile paths, leading to extra `\`'s, 2) Personally think it is a good idea to use `%appdata%` environment variable, so that both the drive and differing paths on standard/customized Windows installs aren't an issue, 3) I think that the last path will be Vista +, right? 4) Are you sure that it is "Apple computer", and not just "Apple"?

Comment: However, are you aware of WLAN connection failures in these logs, or just other ones? On another note - Interesting tool you linked to... Will have to check that out. Lastly, upon returning to this page moments ago, I saw a prompt that there was 2 answers to this question - Did you see/know anything about, the other?

Comment: I am not quite sure with the Windows paths because I haven't used Windows in a while. So the Windows paths are from memory :)

Comment: I do not know how to get the crash logs via Linux. But my first attempt would be to mount the iOS device under Linux and do a search for CrashReporter or log..

Comment: %appdata% edited

Comment: I haven't seen a second answer.. maybe deleted?